# Help with reading tab delimited excel file into SQL database!

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to read in a tab delimited excel file into a SQL database using c#.

Anyone have any suggestions or know of any good resources that would help with this?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? If Sybase or MS SQL Server then you could do this directly using bcp rather than writing a C# app

Comment: SSIS might be a good start.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx

Comment: I am using MS sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just used streamreader and dbaccess.

Answer (score 0):

For reading the CSV itsself I'd recommend you use [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) from Sebastien Lorion because it will save you a lot of hassle parsing the CSV.

From here you could process each row line-by-line (loop over csv.ReadNextRecord()) or perhaps [bulk copy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhilsi/archive/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app.aspx) it if you have a lot of data to avoid all the database hits.

I'm not an expert on this kind of thing, but that works for me anyway.

edit: sorry, I missed the Excel part of your question and assumed it was a flat file.